# Permissions Issue creating folder on remote host with Jenkins

Tags: permissions, mkdir, jenkins

I'm having an issue with using Jenkins to create a folder on a remote host.

The remote host in this case is a stock Ubuntu 20.04 AMI EC2 server with the default `ubuntu` user.

I am connecting with the `ubuntu` user to the remote server with the code below:

```
sshagent(credentials : [branchConfig.SSH_CREDENTIALS_NAME]) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ' + branchConfig.SSH_USER + '@' + branchConfig.DOCKER_HOST + ' "echo \"running whoami\" && whoami && echo \"running groups\" && groups && install --directory --mode 0755 --owner ' + branchConfig.SSH_USER + ' --group ' + branchConfig.SSH_USER + ' ~/importengine"'
}
```

This outputs the following error:

```
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@x.x.x.x echo running whoami && whoami && echo running groups && groups && install --directory --mode 0755 --owner ubuntu --group ubuntu ~/importengine
Warning: Permanently added 'x.x.x.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

running whoami
ubuntu
running groups
ubuntu docker
install: cannot change owner and permissions of ���/home/ubuntu/importengine���: Operation not permitted
```

I can see that the folder gets created, but it has the following permissons:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4.0K Oct 13 11:12 importengine
```

If I delete the folder and run the following command (when logged in as ubuntu):

```
install --directory --mode 0755 --owner ubuntu --group ubuntu ~/importengine
```

...then the folder gets created with the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Oct 13 11:24 importengine
```

#### Question

**Why is the folder getting created as owned by root in the first place?** After all, I can clearly see that `whoami` outputs as `ubuntu`, and not `root` in the error output so it should be creating the folder as if the ubuntu user.

Comment: Look into `man install`. `--owner` is super-user only. Also, according to synopsis, `--directory` should be the last flag.

Comment: I get the same thing if I just run a `mkdir ~/importengine` and only switched to using `install` when that didn't work. Any ideas why the folder is getting created as owned by root?

Comment: I just tried this with `install --directory --mode 0755 --owner panki --group panki ~/test`, can not reproduce (Debian Buster).

Comment: Perhaps the folder in question already exists before running the install command?

Comment: @jayhendren no, i've been manually deleting it an having this issue every time I retry with diferent attempts.

Comment: just because you're manually deleting it doesn't mean nothing else is creating it.  it looks like you already have some echo debug statements checking things like user and group just before running the install command.  have you tried adding an "ls -l" or similar in there?

Answer (score 0):

**In the end, I was unable to figure out what was causing the issue so I had to work around it** by creating the folder of files locally and then scp that across, which did the trick. E.g.

```
sshagent(credentials : [SSH_CREDENTIALS_NAME]) {
    // copy over the .env file in a subfolder. Have to use scp because of strange permissions issue.
    sh 'mkdir -p ~/importengine && cp ' + ENV_FILEPATH + ' ~/importengine/.env'
    sh 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -r ~/importengine ' + SSH_USER + '@' + DOCKER_HOST + ':~/.'
}
```

#### Side Note

This issue really confused my colleagues and me. I and figure it must be Jenkins specific somehow. I was not able to reproduce this issue by running any of the steps manually from my Linux machine (e.g. outside of Jenkins).